# Unable to create tag due to another existing one is almost the same

Tags: support, tags

I am the owner of the project [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager), which is aimed to automate the binary management of Selenium WebDriver for Java. My idea was to create the tag `webdrivermanager` to discuss issues about the tool on stackoverflow.

The problem is that another similar tag already exists: `webdriver-manager`, but this tag is related with a different project: [webdriver-manager](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/), which is quite similar but for Node.js. This project uses almost the same name than mine, even when my project was created first, but that's a different story.

The thing is I am not allowed to create the `webdrivermanager` tag. I get the following error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [webdrivermanager]; however the tag [webdriver-manager] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

In your opinion, what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: `[java-webdriver-manager]`?

Comment: Well, yes, I was thinking in something similar: `webdrivermanager-java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use [webdrivermanager-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdrivermanager-java) as the tag.